# pass variable from javascript function to php

Tags: php, javascript

i have javascript function and it returns a sum variable. But i couldnt reach it from php code.

my function is :

```
function add()
{
    var sum = 0; // sum initially equals to zero.
    var newNumber = 0; // Since textfields are initially text format, I convert them into integer and equalled to newNumber variable.
    if(document.RodeoForm.checkbox.checked == true) // If checkbox changed to true,
    {
        for(var i=0;i<<?php echo $_SESSION['us']; ?>;i++) // Since we have 3 numbers, loop will work 3 times.
        {

             newNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("fiyat"+i).value); // Take the number from field and convert it into an integer.
             sum += newNumber; // Add the numbers into each other.
        }

     }

     document.RodeoForm.tf.value = sum; // Print the sum onto the screen.
}
```

Comment: That JavaScript function doesn't *return* anything. It injects its results into the DOM. You say you can't read the result from PHP code … but you haven't shown us how you are attempting to pass the result to PHP.

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by " But i couldnt reach it from php code."

Comment: You need to give more details. Is the variable set ? Have you tried to war_dump($_SESSION['us']) ?

Comment: this function works fine. i just want to reach the sum variable from other part of the page. i just want to do $sum2=(sum variable in javascript) outside the javascript.

Comment: If this function works fine, then show us the function that doesn't work fine. Otherwise we're just shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript runs on client side, whereas PHP runs on server side. They can't communicate directly with each other.
Once the page is rendered (and sent to the user), all PHP code was executed and is no longer visible in the source.  The JavaScript however is sent along with the HTML and will be executed in the browser of the client.  If you want PHP to be aware of a value generated by JavaScript, you have to manually send the data using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can only reach PHP from JavaScript using AJAX. Google how to do AJAX calls from Javascript.

Comment: these statements are misleading, you have to define what is reach. you can also reach via a regular form post

Comment: @DevZer0 Now you can post proper answer, if you have time. :)

Comment: i am taking the day off like you said @YogeshSuthar i am tired today man

Comment: @DevZer0 Happy resting..:)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `session_start();` to the beginning of that php file, or in the php file which includes that code.

Comment: I'd imagine this is OP's original problem... is trying to output a session variable, but most likely (this is an educated guess entirely based on how the OP codes) he didn't execute session_start()

Answer (score 0):

You can add PHP into Javascript but not the other way around because PHP is server side, so it can echo information into client slide.

Depending on what you're using this for , you can use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send the information to a PHP page.